# List index out of range - python array error

Tags: python, arrays

File "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Tetris!\tetris.py", line 206, in typeSet
    Globals.blockArray[i].x.append(7)
IndexError: list index out of range

I get the above error for the 4th line in typeSet

At initialization:

```
def main():
    initialize()

def initialize():
    Globals.running = True
    addBlock()

class Globals:
    running = True
    blockArray = []
    blockNum = 0
```

And then later on:

```
def addBlock():
    Globals.blockArray.append(block())

class block:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = Globals.blockNum
        Globals.blockNum += 1
        self.x = []
        self.y = []
        self.landed = False
        self.blockType = 1#random.randint(1,6)
        self.typeSet()


    def typeSet(self):
        i = self.id
        if self.blockType == 1:
            #square(i)
            Globals.blockArray[i].x.append(7)
            Globals.blockArray[i].y.append(0)
            Globals.blockArray[i].x.append(7)
            Globals.blockArray[i].y.append(1)
            Globals.blockArray[i].x.append(8)
            Globals.blockArray[i].y.append(0)
            Globals.blockArray[i].x.append(8)
            Globals.blockArray[i].y.append(1)
```

Edit: added more code and switched it so the id should start at 0.  Error code hasn't changed

Comment: Seems pretty clear: whatever `Globals.blockArray` is, it doesn't have `i` members.

Comment: This seems to fail on it's first time through though.  At initialization:    blockArray = [] and then blockNum = 0
and then later on

    def addBlock():
        Globals.blockArray.append(block())

Comment: `i` is never 0 though. You increment it first thing to 1. `blockArray[1]` doesn't exist.

Comment: Arrgh, hang on, `Globals.blockArray[i]` is supposed to be the `block` object you're dealing with? Why on Earth don't you just refer to `self` then?

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.  The reason i didn't originally have it that way was because typeset was outside the class.  But thanks a lot for catching it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough code. The error tells you the exact problem. `Globals.blockArray` does not have a member at position `i`. That's why you shouldn't work with global variables when you can avoid them, since it can be a hard time making sure your global variables have the expected values in them.

Answer (score 0):

While nothing immediate comes to mind looking at your code above, the first thing I would try would be to print the contents of `Globals.blockArray`, and `Globals.blockArray[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you want to do

```
Globals.blockArray.append(self)
```

in the init function, and also increase Globals.blockNum **after** the assignment to self.id.

Answer (score 0):

Every time an instance of `block` is created, `Globals.blockNum` is incremented by 1 and `self.id` is set to the *current value* of `Globals.blockNum`.

Later (in `typeSet`) `self.id` is used to index into `Globals.blockArray`.

The error occurs when `Globals.blockArray` doesn't have at least `self.id + 1` items in it.

If `Globals.blockNum` keeps increasing and its value is used (indirectly) to index into `Globals.blockArray`, this will likely cause the error (unless something causes `Globals.blockArray` to keep growing too.